# JSFiddle - Use POST request error

Tags: javascript, post, angularjs, jsfiddle

I've looked at several other SO questions about this same error, but they don't seem to quite match what I'm doing.

I'm working up an **[AngularJS app & trying to do pagination within JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/L7CSD/6/)**. When I click on my link, I get an error: `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

Most sources say that I need to simply change my form method. But no where am I using GET or POST, so not sure where the hangup is happening. Even tried setting breakpoints, but that didn't help much.

Help would be appreciated!

**`note- To get the same error message: you need to select "RUN" & then click on the link`**

Comment: Your fiddle is broken, nothing appears to work correctly.

Comment: Basically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11528644/1553481) applies. You cannot do a full-blown web application in jsfiddle, particularly no form submission. BTW, clicking on the link does nothing in your example. It also doesn't show the error you mentioned. Have you updated your latest version and given the current link?

Comment: @Mark Haha. yep. That is the reason for the question... the error message...

Comment: @likeitlikeit ya that is what I was basically understanding. But where am I actually submitting a form? I have a link that is calling a function & it is using hardcoded data

Comment: I honestly cannot tell because I don't get the error message. Basically just nothing happens. Visit the jsfiddle link in a new browser tab to verify.

Comment: @likeitlikeit ahh. ok. I can see that. I was able to get it working tho. I had clicked on my link a couple of times. Nothing happened. Then I clicked run & then the link again & it worked.

Comment: Add onclick="return false;" to your href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first link to the jsfiddle it works because the frame shows `http://fiddle.jshell.net/enigmarm/L7CSD/6/show/`.  When you click **RUN** it posts the form to `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/` to render your page.  Going to `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/` in the browser (ie: using GET) will give you the error.

You have an href="" which means that clicking it regets the page using the GET verb instead of the post that created the rendered page.  Don't put href="" on that or stop it from requesting the page.

Comment: Well that fixed the error message. Didn't even think along that line. I removed the `<a>` link and replaced it with a button. But of course, now the app doesn't do anything. So need to dive a bit deeper.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when using a XSS script-blocker like `NoScript`, which changes cross-site requests from POST to GET.

Comment: Thats it. Couldn't believe it. Was driving me nuts. Thanks.