# Why my toggle visibility javascript function is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, function, include

I have this folder structure:

```
htdocs/
  - a.php
  - plugin/
      - b.php
  - website/
      - c.php
  - js/
      - common.js
```

I have these functions on `common.js`:

```
function togglevisibility (id)
{
    var doc = document.getElementById(id);
    if (doc.style.display == "" || doc.style.display == "block") doc.style.display = "none"; else
    if (doc.style.display == "none") doc.style.display = "block";
}

function gotourl (url)
{
    window.location = url;
}
```

Now, let's say I have this script on `a.php`:

```
include_once "plugin/b.php";
include_once "website/c.php";
```

And then, `b.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
```

And then, `c.php`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="togglevisibility('data');">show data</a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="
    var doc = document.getElementById('data');
    if (doc.style.display == '' || doc.style.display == 'block') doc.style.display = 'none'; else
    if (doc.style.display == 'none') doc.style.display = 'block';">
    display data</a>

<div id="data" style="display:none">This is the data</div>

<a href="#" onclick="gotourl('www.google.com');">goto google.com</a>
```

And then we run the site using `http://localhost/a.php`.

The problem is that `gotourl` function is working, but `togglevisibility` function (on link `show data`) isn't working. And if I copy paste the function's contents into the inline javascript (like the `display data` link), it's working. Can you give a hint on where this went wrong? I have searching the problem for hours. Everything seems correct.

Comment: You should really look into jQuery. With it, doing something like this would be far easier.

Comment: Do you have something in the console ? or maybe 404 errors on the dev tools network tab ?

Comment: @BaileyHerbert I should have. But as sometimes jQuery inexplicably unavailable (not included or included but cannot be used) in the collaboration project on the office, I think I will try to master the basic as well as jQuery in tandem, just in case. :)

Comment: @CamilleHodoul nope, nothing comes up. And nothing happens. I use Firebug.

Comment: It's working for me (copy&paste of code)... at least on Firefox

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/JT93H/ yields a `ReferenceError: togglevisibility is not defined {"error": "Please use POST request"}` when clicking on show, but works on clicking on display.

Comment: @mTorres yes, that's what bothering me, as I stated on the question. It works on copy and paste. We can't keep copying and pasting all the codes that doesn't work when function-ified all over the project, right? :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier ouw, that's new. my firebug doesn't give any error indication before. let me look at the error report you provided. thanks!

Comment: If you use [event subscribing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of inline declaration (*onclick*), it works, i don't know the reason, though :-) BTW see it working: [http://jsfiddle.net/JT93H/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/JT93H/2/)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, this error is due the fact that jsFiddle does not accept GET request, only POST and the link is a relative one. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528621/please-use-post-request-in-jsfiddle) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="e.com">E</a>
```

The "href" is the URL, so you should replace 'window.location' with 'window.location.href'.

See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

And for your togglevisibility(), I'm not sure.